# DISTINCT function in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am running into issues with  `DISTINCT`  in MS ACCESS.

Here is what I would like to run and which works in MySQL:

```
SELECT `orig`.`SONG TITLE`,`orig`.`PUBLISHER`
FROM `Sheet1` AS `orig`
INNER JOIN `Sale type` AS `Sale`
ON orig.`CFG DESCRIPTION`=Sale.`CFG DESC`
GROUP BY orig.`SONG TITLE` , orig.`PUBLISHER`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Sale type`.`CFG DESC`) > 1
;
```

The error message I get is:

`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT Sale type.CFG DESC) > 1'.`

Comment: Are you using a passthru query or are you using ODBC?

Comment: in MySQL, this is wrong: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Sale type`.`CFG DESC`) > 1` (remove `>1`)

Comment: Usually, you deal with this kind of situation using two queries or subqueries in Access. See for instance http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/having-count-distinct-t2247016.html

Answer (score 2):

Since `SELECT DISTINCT` is supported in Access, but `COUNT(DISTINCT` is not, you can use a subquery for `SELECT DISTINCT` and base `GROUP BY`, `COUNT` and `HAVING` on the subquery.

```sql
SELECT sub.`SONG TITLE`, sub.PUBLISHER
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            orig.`SONG TITLE`, orig.PUBLISHER, Sale.`CFG DESC`
        FROM
            Sheet1 AS orig
            INNER JOIN `Sale type` AS Sale
            ON orig.`CFG DESCRIPTION`=Sale.`CFG DESC`
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY sub.`SONG TITLE`, sub.PUBLISHER
HAVING COUNT(sub.`CFG DESC`) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

From w3schools.com:

> Note: COUNT(DISTINCT) works with ORACLE and Microsoft SQL Server, but
>   not with Microsoft Access.

Comment: How can I reach the desired functionality without DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

If the query does work in MySQL, then a passthrough query will allow it to continue to work.  See screenshot for area in MS Access for passthrough query..

[image]